# Set rqt_gui Perspectives from Command Line

Tags: ros, rqt-gui, gui, rqt

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm currently writing a script to start rqt_gui with just the right preferences without any setup. So far I've been able to get the rviz preferences to be correct by copying a saved .vcg file to the ~/.rviz/ directory, where it stores such settings. I was hoping I could do something similar for rqt_gui.

My question is how do I make rqt_gui recognize a .preferences file from the command line? I know how to start up rqt_gui using the -p command to set the startup perspective, the problem is getting rqt_gui to recognize this perspective when opened for the first time.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/53721/set-rqt_gui-perspectives-from-command-line/) by [jker](https://answers.ros.org/users/2097/jker/) on ROS Answers with karma: 115 on 2013-01-30

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) on 2021-11-19**:
Years later though, this thread might be a duplicate of https://answers.ros.org/question/79141/rqt-loading-with-requested-perspective/ where you'll find more discussions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

A few year later (hoping that someone will find this useful):

```
<launch>
    <node name="my_rqt_dashboard" pkg="rqt_gui" type="rqt_gui" respawn="false" output="screen" args="--perspective-file $(find my_pkg_with_rqt_config)/rqt_config/my_dashboard.perspective"/>
</launch>
```

---

Originally posted by [ticotico](https://answers.ros.org/users/58821/ticotico/) with karma: 212 on 2021-11-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) on 2021-11-19**:
I made this as a chosen answer as it's more direct (and systematic, non-manual) solution.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Afaik there's no way currently for you to give `rqt_gui` configuration on its 1st boot. @Dirk Thomas or @Dorian Scholz have the full answer. But assuming there's no such thing, I would suggest open an enhancement ticket [here](https://github.com/ros-visualization/qt_gui_core/issues?page=1&sort=updated&state=open).

Sound like you've already been aware of many `rqt`'s feature but as a recap, `rqt_gui`-level setting (the plugins opened last time, their layout a.k.a `perspective` etc.) is stored automatically when you successfully close its process (in `~/.config/ros.org/rqt_gui.ini` by default on Ubuntu. Don't know how this works in other platform). But what you are asking is probably plugin-level setting, and also on its initial boot.

---

Originally posted by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) with karma: 10937 on 2013-01-30

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jker](https://answers.ros.org/users/2097/jker/) on 2013-01-31**:
Actually, this is just what I needed. Apparently the rqt_gui.ini file stores the parameters for the perspective, so as long as I copy that I can get the desired effect. Thanks!